# Jquery loads only after F5 in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am using Jcrop jQuery to crop an image in an MVC3 application.

The following is my JavaScript function:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#imgLab').Jcrop(
        {
            onChange: showCoords,
            onSelect: coordsSelected,
            onRelease: clearCoords
        }
        );
});
```

Image ID is 'imgLab'.

```
<img id="imgLab" src="@ViewBag.ObjLabTypeMaster.TopologyImagePath" alt="Lab" width="500" height="450" />
```

Image src path is coming from database.

Now this works fine in FF, Safari and Chrome.
In IE it only works after I press F5.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to set **AllowSelect:true**   for IE

```
jQuery(function ($) {

        $('#imgLab').Jcrop(
        {
            allowSelect: true,
            //onChange: showCoords,
            //                onSelect: coordsSelected,
            onRelease: clearCoords,
            onDblClick: opendetails
        }, function () {
            Jcrop_Api = this;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding 'defer' to your script tag:

```
<script defer>
    // Your code
</script>
```

Or, you could try waiting until the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#imgLab').Jcrop({
        onChange: showCoords,
        onSelect: coordsSelected,
        onRelease: clearCoords
    });

});
```

hth

Answer (score -1):

I don't know but you could try this and if it doens't work better why don't you ignore IE and say the page is not available in IE or all feature's aren't avaible, or perhaps you could auto reload the page automatically if the person is using IE

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#imgLab').Jcrop(function() {
                onChange: showCoords,
                onSelect: coordsSelected,
                onRelease: clearCoords
            });
        });
</script>
```

And to autoreload the page use following code,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
<!-- content being the secounds before reload -->
```

I'm sure you can add that or not add it with some PHP code.

Comment: it is working but it will reload page after every 30 sec.,Which i don't want.

Comment: Well if your using the first code I sent u you shouldn't be needing the 2nd code, although if my first code doesn't work you can try using the 2nd code although u'll prbbly have to change the "content" value to something like "1" or "0". But like I said if it's working with the first code you don't need the 2nd